# Файл Authenticate.php где находиться

Tags: php, laravel

Где находиться Authenticate.php? Файл в более ранних версиях он располагался так app/HTTP/Middleware/ , а сейчас его там нету.
[image]

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.2

```
'app/http/middleware/Authenticate.php'
```

Laravel 5.3

```
'app/exceptions/handler.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php